# How can i restart my azure VM

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

I'm curious about Azure virtual machines and sharepoint farm solution.after configure sharepoint for 3 days after i had problem,Failed to start virtual machine. While i press restart button it shows error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50dXE.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**According to your screenshot, it seems that you reach the spending limit.**
When your usage results in charges that exhausts the monthly amounts included in your offer, the services that you deployed will be disabled for the rest of that billing month. For example, Cloud Services that you deployed are removed from production and your Azure virtual machines are stopped and de-allocated. To prevent your services from being disabled, you can choose to remove your spending limit. When your services are disabled, the data in your storage accounts and databases will be available in a read-only manner for administrators. At the beginning of the next billing month if your offer includes credits over multiple months, your subscription will be re-enabled and you can re-deploy your Cloud Services and have full access to your storage accounts and databases.

**Because you are on free trial, you have the ability at any time within 90 days after your hitting your spending limit to re-enable your subscription and have it automatically upgrade to our standard Pay-As-You-Go offer.** 
More information please refer to the following [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/spending-limits/):

Answer (score 2):

You ran out of credits. That's why. Your subscription was probably disabled and you can't change status of any resource during this time.

Comment: if i delete other things like not so usable VM2 , what you think this going to help me in restart my VM1.